# WordPress theme development: excerpt issue

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

could someone help me on fix [this theme](http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/rockers/2.0.8/)'s excerpt? It shows the whole posts in the homepage and if I switch to the_excerpt() it will show a not-linked Continue reading text.
Thanks.

Comment: What you have tried so far and can you paste the code here, so we can help answer.

Comment: yes please share code that you have use for getting post data, it will help us to getting you exactly

Comment: All the code is in the WP repo.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in the functions.php file in that theme. It will add a link to the excerpt.

```
// Replaces the excerpt "more" text by a link
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
       global $post;
    return '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> Read the full article...</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Comment: cannot archieve nothing good. I used those functions in functions.php by adding the <a> in my excerpt_more filter, then I use content.php to show the content using get_template_part(). I would to show an automatic excerpt in the homepage/frontpage, but using the current content.php code I only can show the full posts in the home. Cannot archieve where to add the_excerpt() in content.php. At all. Sorry to ask this and thanks for your time.

Comment: Seems that I solved the issue by using if ( is_search() || is_home() || is_front_page() ) : ?> <div class="post-summary"> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> </div> <?php else : the_content(); ?> ... Instead try the wrong way as before: <?php if ( is_search() && is_home() ) : the_excerpt(); Thanks to all.